# Wordpress - whole sidebar as lin to a page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I included the latest post widget. Now I don't want direct to that certain single post but to a page instead. Shall I declare the whole sidebar as a link and wrap it in a  tag. How is the code in PHP?

PHP

```
 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

HTML link

```
<a href="page.html">  <?php get_sidebar(); ?> </a>
```

Comment: A sidebar is not a link. It is for sidebar content. It is hard to understand why you are trying to do this. And you could just try to wrap it in a A tag and see what happens, i would not recommend doing that, but atleast try it instead of asking if that would work.

Comment: No, that's not a good idea at all.

Comment: what is better then? I want to link to all posts of a category, and the latest is on top of the list

Comment: @user2952265 from the question it look like you want the whole sidebar to be a link. What is it you are trying to do exactly? If there is not functionality in Wordpress, consider checking if there is plugin you can use or consider making one

Comment: why not replace it with a block that you write yourself? your goal is clear and the procedure won't take you much time

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know is the side bar is not a link. get_sidebar() is a function that displays your sidebar content.You should read the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) about this function.

Remove get_sidebar() function from your single.php file and create a new page with a custom template. add get_sidebar() function to that template. Here is an example page template for you

```
<?php 
/**
* Template Name: Custom Template
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div class="main">
   <div class="left-content">

      Your content goes here......

    </div>

    <div class="right-content">

     <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```